# How to create a line break after each 3 characters in one long line?

Tags: text, notepad++, line-breaks, notepad, letter

I want to break the below line into 1000 ones by 3 letters each:

```
 saahaalaasabaaboabsabyaceactaddadoadsadzaffaftagaageagoagsahaahiahsaidailaimainairaisaitalaalbaleallalpalsaltamaamiampamuanaandaneaniantanyapeapoappaptarbarcarearfarkarmarsartashaskaspassateattaukavaaveavoawaaweawlawnaxeayeaysazobaabadbagbahbalbambanbapbarbasbatbaybedbeebegbelbenbesbetbeybibbidbigbinbiobisbitbizboabobbodbogboobopbosbotbowboxboybrabrobrrbubbudbugbumbunburbusbutbuybyebyscabcadcamcancapcarcatcawcayceecelcepchicigciscobcodcogcolconcoocopcorcoscotcowcoxcoycozcrucrycubcudcuecumcupcurcutcwmdabdaddagdahdakdaldamdandapdawdaydebdeedefdeldendevdewdexdeydibdiddiedifdigdimdindipdisditdocdoedogdoldomdondordosdotdowdrydubdudduedugduhduidunduodupdyeeareateauebbecuedhedseekeeleffefsefteggegoekeeldelfelkellelmelsemeemsemuendengenseoneraereergernerrersessetaetheveeweeyefabfadfagfanfarfasfatfaxfayfedfeefehfemfenferfesfetfeufewfeyfezfibfidfiefigfilfinfirfitfixfizfluflyfobfoefogfohfonfopforfoufoxfoyfrofryfubfudfugfunfurgabgadgaegaggalgamgangapgargasgatgaygedgeegelgemgengetgeyghigibgidgiegiggingipgitgnugoagobgodgoogorgosgotgoxgoygulgumgungutguvguygymgyphadhaehaghahhajhamhaohaphashathawhayhehhemhenhepherheshethewhexheyhichidhiehimhinhiphishithmmhobhodhoehoghonhophoshothowhoyhubhuehughuhhumhunhuphuthypiceichickicyidsiffifsiggilkillimpinkinninsionireirkismitsivyjabjagjamjarjawjayjeejetjeujewjibjigjinjobjoejogjotjowjoyjugjunjusjutkabkaekafkaskatkaykeakefkegkenkepkexkeykhikidkifkinkipkirkiskitkoakobkoikopkorkoskuekyelablacladlaglamlaplarlaslatlavlawlaxlaylealedleelegleileklesletleulevlexleylezliblidlielinliplislitlobloglooloplotlowloxluglumluvluxlyemacmadmaemagmanmapmarmasmatmawmaxmaymedmegmelmemmenmetmewmhomibmicmidmigmilmimmirmismixmoamobmocmodmogmolmommonmoomopmormosmotmowmudmugmummunmusmutmycnabnaenagnahnamnannapnawnaynebneenegnetnewnibnilnimnipnitnixnobnodnognohnomnoonornosnotnownthnubnunnusnutoafoakoaroatobaobeobiocaodaoddodeodsoesoffoftohmohoohsoilokaokeoldoleomsoneonoonsoohootopeopsoptoraorborcoreorsortoseoudouroutovaoweowlownoxooxypacpadpahpalpampanpapparpaspatpawpaxpaypeapecpedpeepegpehpenpepperpespetpewphiphtpiapicpiepigpinpippispitpiupixplypodpohpoipolpompoopoppotpowpoxproprypsipstpubpudpugpulpunpuppurpusputpyapyepyxqatqisquaradragrahrairajramranraprasratrawraxrayrebrecredreerefregreiremrepresretrevrexrhoriaribridrifrigrimrinriprobrocrodroeromrotrowrubruerugrumrunrutryaryesabsacsadsaesagsalsapsatsausawsaxsayseasecseesegseiselsensersetsewsexshasheshhshysibsicsimsinsipsirsissitsixskaskiskyslysobsodsolsomsonsopsossotsousowsoxsoyspaspysristysubsuesuksumsunsupsuqsyntabtadtaetagtajtamtantaotaptartastattautavtawtaxteatedteetegteltentettewthethothytictietiltintiptistittodtoetogtomtontootoptortottowtoytrytsktubtugtuituntuptuttuxtwatwotyeudoughukeuluummumpunsupoupsurburdurnurpuseutauteutsvacvanvarvasvatvauvavvawveevegvetvexviavidvievigvimvisvoevowvoxvugvumwabwadwaewagwanwapwarwaswatwawwaxwaywebwedweewenwetwhawhowhywigwinwiswitwizwoewogwokwonwoowopwoswotwowwrywudwyewynxisyagyahyakyamyapyaryawyayyeayehyenyepyesyetyewyidyinyipyobyodyokyomyonyouyowyukyumyupzagzapzaszaxzedzeezekzepzigzinzipzitzoazoozuzzzz
```

Please advise me on how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (...)(?=.)
Replace: $1\r\n
```

### Demo

The pattern `(...)(?=.)` matches and captures any three letters at a time.  Then, we replace with those three letters (`$1`) followed by a break (I used `\r\n`, the Windows line ending; use `\n` if you are on Linux).  Note that the pattern also only matches if the three letters found are *not* the final three letters in the string.  The positive lookahead `(?=.)` avoids adding an unwanted break at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression,

```
.{3}\K
```

with a replacement of:

```
\n
```

might simply do that.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/99C4uq/1) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.